# Compare every element of two files (row wise)

Tags: python-3.x, shell, awk

I have three files and want to compare the each element row wise between two files and want to apply condition statement.

**file1 Example**

```
Aa 1.3
Ca 1.1
Ba 0.8
Da 0.65
Fa 0.63
Ea 0.6
Za 0.4
Ha 0.1
```

**File2 Example**

```
Ca Ba Da Fa Ea Za Ha
Aa Ca Ba Da Fa Ea
```

**File3 Example**

```
Fa Ca Za
Ha Ca Ba Da
```

Now I want to compare the elements of file2 and file3 row wise. If element of particular row of file2 is present in same row of file 3 do something if not than perform other task.

I have tried this but not succeeds

```
NG=`cat file1 | awk 'END{print NR}'`

awk -v N="$NG" '
FNR==NR{
 a[$0]=$0
 next
}
{
 for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
   if($i in a){
   print sqrt((N-M)/M)
  }
 else
 {
  print -sqrt(M/(N-M))
 }}
}' file2 file3
```

where N is the number of rows in file1 and M is the numbers of fields in particular row of file3. file2
So my expected output file is like

```
 1.29099 -0.774597 -0.774597 1.29099 -0.774597 1.29099 -0.774597
 -1 1 1 1 -1 -1
```

Comment: You're storing entire line into the array, but looking up by individual field. `$i in a` will always fail for the given input.

Comment: In the expected output, 4th value of 1st row should be 2?

Comment: What does `file1` have to do with the task at hand? `N` could just be some number; where it comes from doesn't seem particularly important.

Comment: Exactly, It doesn't have any significance in processing the file. Just a value used in computation.

Comment: @chepner I have to run  more than 500 random model and evert time size of the file i is different. it is important to take input from the number of rows in file1

Comment: @EdMorton Sir 2 and -3 are just supposed valued for the above mathematical equation

Comment: @RaviSaroch *You* need to do that, but it's not related to the question you are asking us to answer. It could be omitted from the question, as it's just a distraction.

Comment: @EdMorton  I make changes in my the expected output as suggested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below `awk` script.

```sh
awk -v N="$(wc -l < file1)" '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {arr[$i]}; M=NF; getline<"file2"; for (i=1; i<=NF; i++){if ($i in arr){printf "%f ", sqrt((N-M)/M)} else{printf "%f ", -sqrt(M/(N-M))}}; delete arr; print ""}' file3
```

##### Expanded version:

```sh
awk -v N="$(wc -l < file1)" '{
    for (i=1;i<=NF; i++) {
        arr[$i]
    }
    M = NF
    getline < "file2"
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        if ($i in arr) {
            printf "%f ", sqrt((N - M) / M)
        } else {
            printf "%f ", -sqrt(M / (N - M))
        }
    }
    delete arr
    print ""
}' file3
```

Comment: 1st row of the output is perfect. but as per example 5 value in row 2 of file2 is not present in the 2nd row of 3rd file. so output should be negative. but it gives positive value. similarly it happening with all other rows

Comment: In present case it search the entire file3 not the particular row

Comment: @RaviSaroch I've updated the answer, please try it now.

Comment: Please see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline for when and how to call `getline`.

Answer (score 2):

From the text in your question it sounds like this might be what you're trying to do:

```
$ cat tst.awk
FILENAME == ARGV[1] {
    n = FNR
}
FILENAME == ARGV[2] {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        keys[FNR,$i]
    }
    presVals[FNR] = sqrt( (n - NF) / NF )
    abstVals[FNR] = -sqrt( NF / (n - NF) )
}
FILENAME == ARGV[3] {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        val = ( (FNR,$i) in keys ? presVals[FNR] : abstVals[FNR] )
        printf "%s%s", val, (i<NF ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file3 file2
1.29099 -0.774597 -0.774597 1.29099 -0.774597 1.29099 -0.774597
-1 1 1 1 -1 -1
```

but it seems like your expected output doesn't match your sample input so idk if that's what you really want or not.

Don't use all-upper-case variables names like `N` and `M` by the way to avoid clashing with builtin variables and obfuscating your code by making it look like you're using builtin variables when you aren't.

Comment: This looks more polished!! Nice solution 